# How can this Superconformal Field Theory anticommutator be computed for specific charges?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry

I'm following Kinney, Maldacena... work on the superconformal index. (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510251, see the appendix for conventions) It is given in the appendix the anticommutator relationship ($\mathcal{N}=m$):
$$\{S_{\alpha i},Q^{\beta j}\}=\delta_i^j(J_1)_\alpha^\beta +\delta_\alpha^\beta R_i^j+\delta_ i^j\delta_\alpha^\beta\left(\frac{H}{2}+r\frac{4-m}{4m}\right)$$

And it is computed for simple supersymmetry $\mathcal{N}$=1, for a chosen $\mathcal{Q}\equiv\mathcal{Q}^{-1/2,1}$ whose $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ quantum numbers are $(j_1^3,j_2^3)=(-1/2,0)$ that has $r=1$, the corresponding result is given:
$$2\{S,Q\}=H-2J_1-\frac{3}{2}r$$
with the convention that $\mathcal{Q}$ has $r=+1$
Could someone expand into the computation?